# Copy files from an USB key to Android device

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app which, among other features, has to copy a file from an USB flash drive to the /oem/media/ folder of the connected Android device.
Is there any way to perform copy using support or native library?

Comment: What do you mean by 'USB key'? A USB flash drive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read OTG USB storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060221/how-to-read-otg-usb-storage)

Comment: Yes USB flash drive